# Func finding item in array , swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, for-loop

Im trying to create a function that returns an index of element we are searching for. 
For example: find index of 5 in array of [10,25,75,5,15].And if there`s no such element, the function just returns -1
Im stuck at this point:

```
func findIndex(ofNum: Int, in array: [Int]) -> Int {
      for item in array { 
                    if item == ofNum {
                               return item
                } else {
                      return -1
                       }
      return -1
    } 


let result = findIndex(ofNum: 5, in: [10,25,75,5,15])
```

Comment: You shouldn't build this function. It's just `firstIndex(of:)` with an un-Swifty API. Use `firstIndex(of:)` instead

Comment: The code doesn't compile and the last `return -1` will never be reached anyway

Comment: This is an algorithms exercise, so im required to create this function using for-loops and if else statements

Comment: @KwonMin-sik your method should return an optional if it doesn't find the number `func findIndex(ofNum: Int, in array: [Int]) -> Int? {
    for index in array.indices where array[index] == ofNum {
        return index
    }
    return nil
}`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 if let item =  array.firstIndex(where:{$0 == ofNum }) {}
```

Comment: Why are you using a predicate? `if let item = array.firstIndex(of: number) {`

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question literally your code works with this syntax

```
func findIndex(ofNum: Int, in array: [Int]) -> Int {
    for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
        if item == ofNum {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}

let result = findIndex(ofNum: 5, in: [10,25,75,5,15])
```

However please use the (much more efficient) syntax provided in Sh_Khan's answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes i totally will use more pragmatic way in the future.